# PivotTableChange Event

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble finding a way to capture any changes within a specific worksheet, within a specific pivot table.

The Pivot is "pivottable6"
The Worksheet is "APAC"

I have placed this code within the APAC worksheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableChange(ByVal Target As Excel.PivotTable6)

With Target
 MsgBox "You performed an operation in the following PivotTable: " & .Name & " on " & Sh.Name
End With

End Sub
```

But I keep getting an error. Any ideas on how to fix it?

---

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetPivotTableChangeSync(ByVal Sh As Target, Target As PivotTable)

If Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

MsgBox ("cat")

End If

End Sub
```

this is still coming up with USER TYPE NOT DEFINED ERROR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to refresh the pivot when data in sheet changes ? If yes try below code :

Kindly place this code on the sheet which has the pivot.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Sheets("APAC").PivotTables("pivottable6").RefreshTable

End Sub
```

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error Resume Next

    Application.EnableEvents = False


    With Target
        MsgBox "You performed an operation in the following PivotTable: " & .Address & " on """ & Target.Parent.Name & """Sheet"
    End With


    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Santosh, actually I am looking to just detect ANY changes in the pivot. then apply relevant formatting. Also I am looking to build dynamic charts that update according to how the pivot is refreshed

Comment: @user1717622 i have added `Worksheet_Change` event. You may try that though not very sure if it fits your requirement.

Comment: unfortunately the module already contains a worksheet_change macro, I am looking for pivot table event only as to keep it distinct

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes use of Sh.Name, but Sh is not defined.  Use Me.Name instead.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

    With Target
       MsgBox "You performed an operation in the following PivotTable: " & .Name & " on " & Me.Name
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure?  It works for me.  I will update the above with my code.

Comment: yes this is now functional!  I'm still wandering how one would select an exact pivot table on an exact sheet? Using interesect? 'Dim pt As PivotTable
'Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

'If Intersect(Target, pt.TableRange1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your other question, you need to change the IF statement to something like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetPivotTableChangeSync(ByVal Sh As Target, Target As PivotTable)

  If Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)) Is Nothing Then 
     Exit Sub
  Else
    MsgBox ("cat")
  End If

 End Sub
```